# Dart Future.delayed recursively

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter project I need to refresh a display. I am using the code below.

```
Future onRefresh() async {
    // Do some queries which can take quite long

    // Delay for some time before refresh again to avoid overloading the server
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 30), onRefresh);
}
```

My question is, will this eventually cause the stack overflow?

I can't use a priodic timer here, since I don't know how long the querires will take. I only wish it pause for 30 secs between the queries.

Comment: No, it should not be possible to cause a stack overflow.  `await Future.delayed(..., onRefresh)` will queue a call to `onRefresh` that will run on some future iteration of the event loop.  `onRefresh` therefore can't call itself synchronously.  You do need to take care that `onRefresh` isn't called from somewhere else while another call to `onRefresh` is pending.

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for the info. I take a look at the Event Loop architecture. Seems like I need to remove the ``await`` before the ``Future.delayed``. Otherwise the stack will overflow.

Comment: Oops, true, you will need to remove the final `await` since that would result in an infinite callback chain.